# How do I insert a string before my LINQ-created string?

Tags: c#, string, io

Here's my code:

```
var OutputText = listData.Select( x => x.Name, blah, blah, blah) )
string FilePath = @"C:\data.txt";
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FilePath, OutputText);
```

`OutputText` is a bunch of strings created by using a `Select` statement.  The above code works and I am happy with its results.  However, now I would like to insert another string before `OutputText`... The string is basically column headers followed by a carriage return.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep the "streaming" enumeration you need to concatenate the first line into it:

```
var OutputText = listData.Select( x => x.Name, blah, blah, blah) );
string FilePath = @"C:\data.txt";
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FilePath, Enumerable.Repeat(myHeaderString, 1)
    .Concat(OutputText));
```

Comment: Unlike the other solution this option maintains the streaming property of the algorithm; it doesn't require the entire file's data to be read into memory first.

Comment: Thanks Servy and Mark Hurd!

Answer (score 4):

```
var outputText = listData.Select(x => x.Name, blah, blah, blah)).ToList();
outputText.Insert(0, myHeaderString);
// rest of code here
```

Comment: Unlike the OP's, code, this doesn't stream the data, this evaluates the entire result set into memory before writing it.  Additionally, inserting an item to the start of a list requires all of the other items to be moved down, which is somewhat expensive.

Answer (score 1):

May be something like:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
builder.AppendLine("HEADER STRING"); 

var OutputText = listData.Select( x => x.Name, blah, blah, blah) ); 
builder.Append(OutputText);

string FilePath = @"C:\data.txt";
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FilePath, builder.ToString());
```

Comment: Unlike the OP's, code, this doesn't stream the data, this evaluates the entire result set into memory before writing it.

Comment: @Servy: correct observation. I just didn't get deeper in optimization for this case, just only tend to ADD, and not INSERT like an accepted solution.